# Async function makes it hard to access variable because variable is not "ready" when it is needed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, expo

I have problems with my variable **keys**. getAllKeys saves keys into the variable **keys**. I want to use **keys** in prepareDate but when the code gets to prepareDate it does not work because the values are not yet asignt to variable **keys** (because of this JavaScript Async stuff)

I need to know how I can wait until **keys** is "ready" so prepareDate (and the rest of the code) can work with **keys**. There is .then and promise (if this is the right solution) but I do not know how to use them here.

```
  let keys = [];

  const getAllKeys = async () => {
    try {
      keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
    } catch (e) {
      // read key error
    }
    console.log("keys: ", keys) // This works, the keys are saved inside keys
  }

  const getData = async (key) => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
    } catch (e) {
      // error reading value
    }
  };

  const prepareData = () => {
    console.log("keys: ", keys)
    keys.forEach((key) => {   // I want that this works but there is nothing inside keys.. 
      console.log("hier")
      console.log(getData(key))
    })
  }

  getAllKeys();
  prepareData();
```

Answer (score 2):

Stop using a global variable `keys`. Instead, `return` a value from `getAllKeys` (so that `getAllKeys()` returns a promise for that), and accept the keys as a parameter to `preprateData`:

```
const getAllKeys = async () => {
  try {
    return await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
  } catch (e) {
    // read key error
    return [];
  }
};

const prepareData = async (keys) => {
  const data = Promise.all(keys.map(key => {
    console.log(key);
    return getData(key);
  }))
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}
```

Now you can use them as

```
getAllKeys().then(prepareData);
```

or in

```
(asnyc () => {
  const keys = await getAllKeys();
  console.log("keys: ", keys) // This works
  await prepareData(keys);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could postpone the call to `prepareData` until after `getAllKeys` is finished, like so:

`getAllKeys().then(prepareData);`

We can do that because `getAllKeys` is an async function and thus returns a Promise, which allows us to call the `then`-method on it.